# value return from function in one script to another script, value is not globally available python

Tags: python, function, scripting, global, openpyxl

have two scripts p1.py and p2.py.

p1.py has something like this

```
if (day=='01'): /*where day=time.strftime("%d")*/
wb=p2.py(day)
for i in range(1,day_list+1):  /* genrates sheet equal to number of  days in a month)
            wb.copy_worksheet(wb['temp'])
            ws=wb['temp Copy']
            ws.title=str(i)
```

Now p2.py have functions to load an excel workbook using openpyxl:

```
wb=load_workbook(filename='.....\....\abc.xlsx')
return wb
```

Now in p1.py:

```
if namesheet in wb.sheetnames:   /* `namesheet:
                                              chk=day[:1]
                                               if(chk=='0'):
                                                    namesheet=day[1:]
                                                else
                                                   namesheet=day */
/*do something */
```

Here , in the if condition I am getting error:

```
name 'wb' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "E:\AshimTest\myscript\Auto_Report.py", line 133, in <module>
    if namesheet in wb.sheetnames:
NameError: name 'wb' is not defined
```

Can someone please help.I think wb is just being local to first if statement.

I am new to python ,how can this be solved ??

Comment: Comments in Python use `#`, not `/* */`.

Comment: Indentation is part of Python's syntax; it's not optional. The code examples do not appear to be indented properly.

Comment: @glich thats not an actual code from python, i was just trying to explain it.

Comment: @glich: there is no problem with indentation on my actual code

Comment: @gilch refer to this image https://i.imgur.com/N80CXrV.png .

Comment: @glich: now can you please answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try this, import load_workbook function from 'p2.py' in 'p1.py' such as:

```
from py2 import load_workbook
```

After that, already in p1.py run

```
wb=load_workbook(filename='.....\....\abc.xlsx')
if namesheet in wb.sheetnames:
...
...
```

Comment: load_workbook is a function from openpyxl. In p1.py I have from openpyxl import load_workbook as well as in p2.py i have from openpyxl import load_workbook.

Comment: both pictures are imports p1.py?

Comment: If you do not override the `load_workbook ()` function, then what prevents you from importing it directly into `p1.py` and use? I can not yet understand why it is necessary to use the variable `wb` of `p2.py`.

Comment: not using the variable wb of p2.py. The image posted was as I was testing that part  so that if error will be fixed but didn't. wb in p1.py is a new variable

Comment: the load_workbook function in p2.py returns actual workbook, which is hold by wb in p1.py

Comment: this is my actual p2.py: https://i.imgur.com/ak2qn79.png. It returns the workbook

Comment: can then import the load () function from p2.py?

Answer (score 0):

oHH !!! what a silly mistake. The if statement to load template only worked for the first day of the month. Logic was wrong here as for the rest days , the template wasn't loaded as it didnt enter the if statement,hence wb had no value and no declaration ,so was not defined.